# Create resource view in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I need to create a resource view in CKAN 2.5, but all the [API documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_view_create) says is:

> ckan.logic.action.create.resource_view_create(context, data_dict)
>
> Creates a new resource view.
>
> Parameters:
>
> resource_id (string) – id of the resource
>
> title (string) – the title of the view
>
> description (string) – a description of the view (optional)
>
> view_type (string) – type of view
>
> config (JSON string) – options necessary to recreate a view state (optional)
>
> Returns:
>
> the newly created resource view
>
> Return type:
>
> dictionary

Nothing is said about the available `view_type`'s nor how to create the required Json for the payload. As much, someone pointed me to http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html, and I can figure out the views are `recline_view`, `recline_grid_view`, etc.

I've tried to create a `recline_view` view, but as said, the Json payload is necessary:

```
$ curl -s -S -H "Authorization: my-api-key" "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/resource_view_create?resource_id=eaf95b46-3a9f-4cbc-87cf-a6364e9581b1&title=view_test&view_type=recline_view"
"Bad request - JSON Error: No request body data"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For curl, you'll need to use the `-d` (`--data`) option with the json string as its value. For example:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/3/action/resource_view_create -d '{"resource_id":"my-resource-id", "view_type":"recline_grid_view", "title":"My recline grid"}' -H "Authorization:my-api-key"
```

Comment: I thought the Json payload was about specific configuration regarding the chosen view. Thanks!